# Taking Clothing ID from website and sending to discord

Tags: javascript, twitter, web, slack, discord

I am trying to code a site monitor for a clothing website. The monitor pings the website, takes note of what is sold out and not sold out, and when something changes it sends an alert via discord, twitter (tweet), or slack. At the moment, I have it so it sends websites base link, then the id to the end of that. This means the update sent to twitter or the other programs is just a link. I am trying to figure out how to with the link send the items name. Here is the code so far that I have. For example of what im trying to do is, Grey Supreme T-Shirt https://supremenewyork.com/greysupremetshirt.

The code I have so far:

```
function postToDiscord(restockedItems)
{  for (let i = 0; i < restockedItems.length; i++) {
    discord.sendMessage('http://www.supremenewyork.com' + 
restockedItems[i]);
  }
}
```

The code that depicts restockedItems is:

```
if (restockCycles != 0) {
          if (newSoldOutItems.length < originalSoldOutItems.length) {
              console.log('RESTOCK OCCURED!!!');
              var restockedItems = 
findArrayDifferences(originalSoldOutItems, newSoldOutItems);
              console.log(restockedItems)
              postToSlack(restockedItems)
              postToDiscord(restockedItems)
              postToTwitter(restockedItems)
              originalSoldOutItems = newSoldOutItems; 
          }
```

As you can see the message that is sent already, what could I do to take the name of the item off the website and send that along with the url.
Thanks

Comment: what is `restockedItems` and how do you get them?

Comment: Restockeditems is a variable I set aside that denotes any new items listed on the website that wasn't there the last time they pinged.

Comment: It would help if you posted the code responsible for setting the variable restockedItems

Comment: check original post

Comment: I was more curious on how you were getting the item details in the first place. Are you scraping the websites html? or are you using an API they offer?

Comment: Scraping the websites HTML, im trying to figure how to get the item id and put that above the link